# Wlan profile to connect to open wi-fi hotspot

Tags: c#, windows, api, configuration, wifi

What's the correct wlan profile to connect to open wi-fi hotspot? I'm using Native WiFi API and following profile:

```
      @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""US-ASCII""?>
        <WLANProfile xmlns=""http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"">
            <name>name_goes_here</name>
            <SSIDConfig>
                <SSID>
                    <name>name_goes_here</name>
                </SSID>                    
            </SSIDConfig>
            <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
            <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
            <MSM>
                <security>
                    <authEncryption>
                        <authentication>open</authentication>
                    </authEncryption>
                </security>
            </MSM>
        </WLANProfile>"
```

But it fails saying that configuration of the network connection profile is corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<WLANProfile xmlns=""http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"">
<name>name_goes_here</name>
<SSIDConfig>
  <SSID>
    <name>name_goes_here</name>
  </SSID>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
<MSM>
  <security>
    <authEncryption>
      <authentication>open</authentication>
      <encryption>none</encryption>
      <useOneX>false</useOneX>
    </authEncryption>
  </security>
</MSM>
</WLANProfile>";
```